# Why .NET CORE HttpClient takes exactly 15 seconds to resolve an API Gateway?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

In my .net-core, I'm calling diffrent external API's.
If the API is in the same cluster, I'm getting an immediate response. But If the external API is hosted through an internal gateway, It takes exactly **15 seconds** to send the request to the internal gateway.

I tried to call this specific API directly from my docker terminal and its receiving the request immediately. Also checked the internal gateway logs and the request is only receiving after 15 seconds after I made a request from the code.

Here is my code.

```
 HttpClientHandler clientHandlerCustPortfolioSecurityHoldings = new() {
   UseProxy = false,
     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
       return true;
     }
 };
 using(var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandlerCustPortfolioSecurityHoldings)) {
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Bearer token");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientId", "test data");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-USER-ID", "test data");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ORG-ID", "test data");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-MSG-ID", "test data");
   httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(_config["EXT_API_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS"]));
   StringContent InputContent = new(JsonSerializer.Serialize(reqparams), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   using(var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https internal gateway URL", InputContent)) {
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
       var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       APICustomResponse apiCustomResponse = new() {
         StatusCode = true,
           ErrorMessage = "Success",
           ResponseData = result
       };
       return await Task.FromResult(apiCustomResponse);
     } else {
       var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       APICustomResponse apiCustomResponse = new() {
         StatusCode = false,
           ErrorMessage = "Failed",
           ResponseData = result
       };
       return await Task.FromResult(apiCustomResponse);
     }
   }
 }
```

Please help me out. It is this constant 15 seconds thing is killing me.

Comment: This is most likely network problem that anything to do with .net core or HttpClient library. Have you tried pinging the endpoint from the machine where you are facing this problem? If the simple ping response is timing out or if there is evidence of slow response/delay etc, most likely you are on the server from where name resolution is not happening as smoothly as it needs to be.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1536343/very-slow-dns-lookup-regardless-of-dns-server-i-use , see if you can try out domain name resolution from the problem machine.

Comment: https://github.com/lowleveldesign/dotnet-wtrace Enable network trace and see into the actual log entries. That can easily answer where the time goes.

Comment: It does sound network-related. 15 seconds could be a 1-sec timeout with 3 exponential retries (1+2+4+8). I recommend installing wireshark to see if that's the case.